# Weird Error in production Web application (W2k8 R2/IIS7 64bit/.NET 3.5)

Tags: windows, .net-3.5, iis-7

after migrating our production web application to a new server we are encountering an error which is quite hard to track down:

```
Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 7.5.7600.16385, time stamp: 0x4a5bd0eb  
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7600.16385, time stamp: 0x4a5bdfe0  
Exception code: 0xebf00baa  
Fault offset: 0x000000000000aa7d  
Faulting process id: 0xc90  
Faulting application start time: 0x01cb9ddb02758bf5  
Faulting application path: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe  
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll  
Report Id: ceecffda-0c1c-11e0-9900-0019998d9a4d
```

Basically, it kills the worker process and restarts the web application afterwards.

WER is unable to produce a dump and even process orphaning in IIS7 does not help -- the worker process is terminated immediately and no dump is created.

The application will run just fine for a couple of days and then crash with this error.

Has anyone ever dealt with this error?

Comment: The only thing I find on this error code, [is a small discussion on codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/3437570/Kernelbase-error-on-Server-2008.aspx) which talks about "that 3.5 was not enabled on the server". I'm not sure if that helps, I've never worked with IIS.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you go to ask for DebugDiag 1.2 beta from Microsoft, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2010/09/30/debug-diag-1-2-beta.aspx

That should give you a dump file to analyze. Or you can share it with Microsoft via http://support.microsoft.com